# PHP: Using Content Disposition Header and Outputting to the Screen

Tags: php, header, download

PHP Content Disposition Header is used to force the browser to output the PHP buffer into the file. That is clear.

Example:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file_saved.ext"');
```

However, there might be situation, when it is needed to output information to both: to the screen and to the file in the same script. Example would be debugging reasons.

Is it therefore possible, in one part of a PHP script, to use `echo` or `print` to output text on the screen, while the other part of the script to save PHP buffer with the help of  Content Disposition Header?

A possible solution could be forcing the PHP buffer output its content on the screen immediately after `echo` while the rest of the script would output content on the file thanks to Content Disposition Header?

Comment: Hey, you can do it with an iframe, for an example: you output the buffer to the screen in the main page, and then you can embed an empty iframe and have the src attribute set this way: src="https://site.com/article.php?id=2&save=1", and check if $_GET['save'] is 1 or 0 . if its 1 send the content disposition header :)

Comment: hi i forgot to mention, you can do it with an invisible iframe..

Comment: @Sirotoshipizdetz: In case you didn't know: You can edit your comment for 5 minutes.

Comment: Debug to a log file, not to the screen in a situation like this. (or with [a proper debugger](http://xdebug.org/)

Comment: @Sirotoshipizdetz, hey. Thanks for the response. It seems a bit complicated. Is there nothing as easy as forcing the output to be displayed by the PHP script after usage of `echo`? In this case, it will be really better to output to the log file.

Comment: @Sirotoshipizdetz, hi I actually use what you advised in your answer. And it is not that difficult at all. If you wish, you can quickly formulate full response to my question, so I can give you credit and close this question.